# How to write unit tests in spec form?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, coding-style, bdd

I have difficulty in many situations to come up with a good unit test names for classes and methods.  Typically, I try to follow the form:

```
public class TestContext
{
    [Fact]
    public void WhenThis_DoThat()
    {
    }
}
```

Some put words Given, When, and Then on the parts to be explicit.  I like it because it seems to make the unit test clearer on what it is that it's testing.
Aside from considering BDD toolkits, I need some advice in how this can work with plain old xUnit tools.

I'm having especially hard time with scenarios like this:

> *When Application starts up, the main form loads and user sees a list of
>   links which the user can click on.*

or maybe a better use case scenario is:

> *User can select a link from a list of
>   links.*

I'm not certain but I'm trying to describe a behavior where you run an app and the form loads with a list of clickable links.  And turning that into a unit test.

What is the Given, When, and Then for that?

Comment: IMO, this has nothing to do with unit-testing. Call that acceptance-testing or functional-testing, but not unit-testing, please.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: I write all of my unit tests in that style.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I write tests in BDD specification style: http://github.com/orfjackal/tdd-tetris-tutorial

What is needed, is the ability to have multiple test fixtures in one class. Then it's possible to organize the tests so, that each fixture is the "Given/When" part and each test method is the "Then" part. JUnit does not support it, so I wrote [a simple test runner](http://github.com/orfjackal/tdd-tetris-tutorial/blob/tutorial/src/test/java/net/orfjackal/nestedjunit/NestedJUnit4.java) for it:

```
@RunWith(NestedJUnit4.class)
public class WerewolfTest extends Assert {
    public class Given_the_moon_is_full {
        @Before public void When_you_walk_in_the_woods() {
            ...
        }
        @Test public void Then_you_can_hear_werewolves_howling() {
            ...
        }
        @Test public void Then_you_wish_you_had_a_silver_bullet() {
            ...
        }
    }
    public class Given_the_moon_is_not_full {
        @Before public void When_you_walk_in_the_woods() {
            ...
        }
        @Test public void Then_you_do_not_hear_any_werewolves() {
            ...
        }
        @Test public void Then_you_are_not_afraid() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Esko, you can get the same behaviour with @RunWith(Suite.class).  It's a bit more elaborate in that you must add also a @Suite.SuiteClasses({MyClass.MySubclass, MyClass.MyOtherSubclass}) but you don't need to depend on anything other than JUnit.  An example is http://thecleancoder.blogspot.com/2010/10/craftsman-62-dark-path.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm quoting [Introducing BDD](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd) from Dan North:

> ### Test method names should be sentences
>
> My first "Aha!" moment occurred as I
>   was being shown a deceptively simple
>   utility called [agiledox](http://agiledox.sourceforge.net/), written by my
>   colleague, Chris Stevenson. It takes a
>   JUnit test class and prints out the
>   method names as plain sentences, so a
>   test case that looks like this:
>
> ```
> public class CustomerLookupTest extends TestCase { testFindsCustomerById() { ... } testFailsForDuplicateCustomers() { ... } ... }
> ```
>
> renders something like this:
>
> ```
> CustomerLookup – finds customer by id – fails for duplicate customers – ...
> ```
>
> The word "test" is stripped from both
>   the class name and the method names,
>   and the camel-case method name is
>   converted into regular text. That’s
>   all it does, but its effect is
>   amazing.
>
> Developers discovered it could do at
>   least some of their documentation for
>   them, so they started to write test
>   methods that were real sentences.
>   What’s more, they found that when they
>   wrote the method name in the language
>   of the business domain,the generated
>   documents made sense to business
>   users, analysts, and testers.

The whole paper is actually worth the read. Warmly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

I try to follow Roy Osherove's approach:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2005/04/03/TestNamingStandards.aspx

Comment: So, to give an example, what would you name the tests which were given as examples in the OP?

Comment: I like Roy's style as well - I bought his Art of Unit Testing book by the way which is very good - but like ChrisW, could you try my example using Roy's approach?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario what can go wrong?  A unit test needs to test something, so what are you testing.

FormHasLinks?

LoadForm?  //then check for links

Maybe if you say what your testing rather than what your doing you might find it easier.

Comment: The thing I am testing in my example is whether the list of links show up on the form when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

I name my tests after the input, not after the output. I describe the scenario which is being tested: I don't try to define, in the name of the test case, what the required output is in that scenario.

For example, the following test the behaviour of the Backspace key in a text editor, in various scenarios:

- Backspace after space
- Backspace around edges of inline textrun
- Backspace at beginning of paragraph
- Backspace near end of line
- Backspace normalize within paragraph
- Backspace selected word and both spaces
- Backspace selected word and space
- Backspace selected word
- Backspace selection spans two paragraphs
- Backspace several words
- Backspace space and selected word
- Backspace to far edge of other block

Thus you can see more-or-less what scenarios are being tested (but it doesn't also try to tell you what the expected behaviour is in each scenario).